# how to add logging before pyramid add_notfound_view and add_exception_view

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid

I am using pyramid framework. In my `__init__.py` , I am using notfound_view_config and exception_view_config decorators to redirect to custom 404 page.

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_mako')
    config.include('pyramid_handlers')
    config.include('pyramid_beaker')
    # set the path for static views
    config_static_views(config)

    # not found view
    config.add_notfound_view(notfound)
    config.add_exception_view(error_view)
    ## more code
    return config.make_wsgi_app()


@notfound_view_config()
def notfound(exc,request):
    #redirect to my custom 404 page

@exception_view_config()
def error_view(exc,request):
    #redirect to my custom 404 page
```

My .ini file code

```
[app:main]
use = egg:package_name

pyramid.reload_templates = false
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en

#-------------------CUSTOM SETTINGS----------------------------------------

pyramid.includes = pyramid_exclog

session.type = memory
# session.data_dir = %(here)s/data/sessions/data
# session.lock_dir = %(here)s/data/sessions/lock
session.key = soe_key
session.secret = some_secret

###
# wsgi server configuration
###

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 5000

[loggers]
keys = root, pyra

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console

[logger_pyra]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = pyra

[logger_exc_logger]
level = ERROR
handlers = exc_handler
qualname = exc_logger

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[handler_exc_handler]
class = FileHandler
args = ('%%(here)s/exceptions.log',)
level = ERROR
formatter = exc_formatter

[formatter_generic]
format = %%(asctime)s %%(levelname)-5.5s [%%(name)s:%%(lineno)s][%%(threadName)s] %%(message)s

[formatter_exc_formatter]
format = %(asctime)s %(message)s
```

Now because I have some issues with my website in production (sometimes I am getting 404 custom page even when link/page exists), that I am not able to replicate on my local machine. I need to add some sort of logging to tell me what is happening when these wrong 404 page pops up.

I am not sure what is the best and easy way to do that.

I tried using pyramid_exclog from [here](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_exclog/en/latest/) but it is not showing me any log details.

I have read a lot of answers on stackoverflow but I am still bit confused what is the best and easy way to print logging information to a file.

Comment: Did you configure it in your .ini, per https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_exclog/en/latest/#setup and https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_exclog/en/latest/#using? Please include your .ini content by editing your question.

Comment: @StevePiercy I have added my .ini file code in the question now. Also, I did configure my .ini file as per that document.

Comment: You have only two keys for `[loggers]`, but define a third `logger_exc_logger`. Try adding that as the third key, and try again. See also Pyramid's docs for [logging](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/logging.html) for more example configuration.

Comment: I do have the third key in my code. If you look after `logger_pyra`

Comment: That's the second key, not the third.

Comment: It is working now. I changed `logger_pyra`  to `logger_my_package_name`